# Heuristic for Turing Completeness?

Tags: computational-complexity, formal-languages

I seem to recall that determining whether a language is Turing complete is an undecidable problem in general, but I was wondering what would work as a rule-of-thumb heuristic that strongly suggests it.

My first thought was that if you are able to output the primes without ever halting, that that would do the trick. My second thought was that that's probably overkill; something like the Fibonacci sequence would probably be enough.

I realize neither of those would be proof, inasmuch as you could write a program that prints out Fibonacci numbers and that's all it does, which clearly is not Turing complete itself. But in a reasonable context with a system you expect might be Turing complete, would either of those be strong indicators that it indeed is? If not, what would? And if so, are there even simpler heuristics that would be pretty reliable?

Comment: A way to actually prove it is to use the language in question to write an interpreter for a language that is known to be Turing complete. There are quite minimal languages that have this property.

Comment: Thanks, but I was aware of that. It seems to me like a Fibonacci outputter might be easier than even an "easy" TC system like cyclic tags or a register machine, so that's more what I'm specifically curious about.

Comment: As celtschk said proving that a given thing is Turing complete is rather trivial, but as everything in computability theory it is also easy to build some program whose  Turing completeness relies on arbitrary hard problems or even undecidable  (if ZFC is inconsistent, return)

Comment: BTW, a simple language able to produce Fibonacci numbers is the following: There are two registers $a$ and $b$ holding integers. On program start, both are initialized to $1$. The language executes commands in the order given by the program, cycling back to the first command after reaching the end. And there are three commands: `OUTPUT` outputs the number in register $a$. `EXCHANGE` exchanges the content of the two registers. `ADD` adds the values of both registers and stores the result in $a$. The program then simply reads `OUTPUT; ADD; EXCHANGE`. This language clearly isn't Turing-complete.